# KB Navigator latest version wont start up Ipad Air 12.5.7

Tags: genexus

I just updated the device to latest iOS version. 12.5.7
Available free space is more than 3gb.
Currently connected to internet.

After a few install/unistall cycles of KB Navigator 18.4 (763)
the app gets installed but it wont stay open more than a few seconds.

The app starts but seems that it cannot load.
It never displays any text.